# npm start (yarn start) error. cannot find @babel/register

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, npm-start

I creact app using react. I usually use yarn start to run my app.
Error messege is "cannot find @babel/register" but there is on the package.json.

**In my package.json**
"@babel/register": "^7.6.2"

**my index.js**

```
require('@babel/register');
module.exports = require('./server.js');
```

Error

```
> reactjs-simple-boilerplate@1.0.0 start
> node src/server/index.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/register'
Require stack:
- /Users/mk/kr/kr-application-bd786050/kr-site/src/server/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mk/kr/kr-application-bd786050/kr-site/src/server/index.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/mk/kr/kr-application-bd786050/kr-site/src/server/index.js'
  ]
}
```

npm install --save-dev @babel/register is not works for me.
After run this code, I got `npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY`

Comment: Can you share the part where you get the `npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY` error?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can help 100% with the given information, but try running the following:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json yarn.lock; npm i
```

That will not only remove your modules, but it'll also remove eventual lock files which are used as conformity for your module versions; It could happen they mismatched versions between installations causing the above error, thus by removing and reinstalling you should solve the problem.

If that's not the case, you might have something off on your package.json, which you'd need to share in order to debug further